# log.txt not displaying {userName} upon login

Tags: c#, winforms

The form is a log-in page. When the submit button is clicked, it should log "User {userName} logged in at {timestamp}" Log-in is successful but the {userName} is just blank in my log.txt file.

**Log Class**

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmgMk.png)

**Log File**

[Log Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaQqG.png)

If anybody can guide me in the right direction, much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the `userName` parameter actually has a non-null non-empty value when you call the method?

Comment: I have nothing in place to handle an exception like that. I figured if I can successfully login using a sqlconnection and command to query the userName and password, then it should be able to GetCurrentUserName() and return userName

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at the start of the userLogin method and check the value of userName. The issue might lie in your GetCurrentUserName() method or elsewhere and not in the code snippet you provided. Maybe it's possible that GetCurrentUserName() is returning nothing because the login failed.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. When I first had the log-in validation wrote, it was catching invalid credentials for all 3 users that are in the DB. Now, I just tested a bad credential input and it logged in anyways. Back to square 1, thanks a bunch

Comment: Wow, I'm halfway stupid when I went back I cut / pasted in the wrong spot. I was validating literally nothing when btnSubmit_Clicked... Sorry for wasting your time but thanks for taking me outside the box.